# Python PIL -> centering long text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I'm trying to put some text over an image with Python.

I want my text to be in the center of the image, no matter how long the text is. This, I've managed to do.

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap

astr = '''The rain in Spain falls mainly on\n the plains. but what if I add some\n more text to this image###################\n##################################?\nThe rain in Spain falls mainly on\n the plains. but what if I add some\n more text to this image###################\n##################################?'''

im = Image.open("source.jpg")
MAX_W, MAX_H = im.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype('font.otf', 28)

w, h = draw.textsize(astr, font=font)

draw.text(((MAX_W - w) / 2, (MAX_H - h) / 2),astr,(255,255,255),font=font)

im.save('test.png')
```

> **My problem?** I also want my text to be centered, and I'm talking about
>   the centering you see (for example) in Microsoft Word, or any basic
>   text editor. Like, the text can be centered to the left, the middle,
>   or the right. [See this image.](http://d2r5da613aq50s.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/192133.image0.jpg)

Comment: If the provided answer solved your problem, please accept it

Answer (score 3):

You are interested in the 'align' argument in http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text - it can be "left", "center" or "right".

```
draw.text(((MAX_W - w) / 2, (MAX_H - h) / 2),astr,(255,255,255),font=font,align="center")
```